# alternately appending elements from two lists

Tags: python, list, append

I have three lists with elements :

```
a = [[0,1],[2,3],...]
b = [[5,6],[7,8],...]

c = []
```

I want to append elements from **a** and **b** into **c** to get:

```
c = [ [0,1],[5,6],[2,3],[7,8],.... ]
```

Comment: do you mean `[5,6]` instead of `[5,3]`?

Comment: What if the lists do not have equal length?

Comment: Do you want to add elements from lists `a` and `b` one by one in turn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another very simple approach using *string slicing* (and **most performance efficient**) as:

```
>>> a = [[0,1],[2,3]]
>>> b = [[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> c = a + b # create a list with size = len(a) + len(b)
>>> c[::2], c[1::2] = a, b  # alternately insert the value
>>> c
[[0, 1], [5, 6], [2, 3], [7, 8]]
```

Below is the comparison of results with `timeit` for the answers mentioned here (Python version: 2.7):

1. Using *string slicing*: 0.586 usec per loop

   ```
   moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m "timeit" -s "a = [[0,1],[2,3]]; b = [[5,6],[7,8]];" "c = a + b; c[::2], c[1::2] = a, b"
   1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.586 usec per loop
   ```
2. Using `itertools.chain()`: 1.89 usec per loop

   ```
   moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m "timeit" -s "from itertools import chain; a = [[0,1],[2,3]]; b = [[5,6],[7,8]];" "c = list(chain(*zip(a, b)))"
   1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 usec per loop
   ```
3. Using `reduce()`: 0.829 usec per loop

   ```
   moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m "timeit" -s "import operator; a = [[0,1],[2,3]]; b = [[5,6],[7,8]];" "c = reduce(operator.concat, zip(a, b))"
   1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.829 usec per loop
   ```
4. Using `list.extend()`: 0.824 usec per loop

   ```
    moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m "timeit" -s "a = [[0,1],[2,3]]; b = [[5,6],[7,8]]; c=[]" "for pair in zip(a,b): c.extend(pair)"
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.824 usec per loop
   ```
5. Using `list.append()` twice: 1.04 usec per loop

   ```
   moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m "timeit" -s "a = [[0,1],[2,3]]; b = [[5,6],[7,8]]; c=[]" "for a_element, b_element in zip(a, b): c.append(a_element); c.append(b_element)"
   1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 usec per loop
   ```

Comment: Ok. But you really should pass `timeit` those setup statements using the `-s` option. FWIW, in Python 3.6 my `[*chain(*zip(a, b))]` is about 10% faster than my `list(chain...)`version, and my list comp is slightly faster than that.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Yes, you are right. I missed that. Updated the answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I am using `Python 2.7`, so could not evaluate it for the syntax you mentioned. But I have already mentioned in my answer that my evaluation is for `Python 2.7`

Answer (score 6):

Basic approach:

```
>>> a = [[0,1],[2,3]]
>>> b = [[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> c = []
>>> for pair in zip(a,b):
...   c.extend(pair)
... 
>>> c
[[0, 1], [5, 6], [2, 3], [7, 8]]
>>>
```

This breaks if the lengths aren't equal. But you can deal with that case as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You could `zip` the two lists and then reduce them to a flat list:

```
import operator
c = reduce(operator.concat, zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two lists are the same length, the most compact way to do this uses `itertools.chain` and `zip`.

```
from itertools import chain

a = [[0,1],[2,3],[10,11],[12,13]]
b = [[5,6],[7,8],[15,16],[17,18]]

c = [*chain(*zip(a, b))]
print(c)
```

**output**

```
[[0, 1], [5, 6], [2, 3], [7, 8], [10, 11], [15, 16], [12, 13], [17, 18]]
```

---

As juanpa.arrivillaga mentions in the comments, that syntax will not work on older versions of Python. Instead, you can do

```
c = list(chain(*zip(a, b)))
```

Here's another option, which doesn't use imports or the `*` splat operator:

```
c = [u for t in zip(a, b) for u in t]
```

---

If you need to handle input lists of unequal length, take a look at the `roundrobin` function in [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Eg,

```
c = list(roundrobin(a, b))
```

Comment: I think you mean `list(chain(*zip(a,b)))` although I kind of *wish* that syntax was supported.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The code I posted works for me on Python 3.6. But I guess I better add the older syntax to my answer.

Comment: Oh! I should start making more wishes!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Python 3.6 is fun. I still haven't explored everything, but format strings (aka f-strings) are extremely addictive. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
merged = []
for a_element, b_element in zip(a, b):
    merged.append(a_element)
    merged.append(b_element)
```

Unless you have very stringent performance requirements, the simplest approach is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`more_itertools`](https://pythonhosted.org/more-itertools/api.html) which implements the `itertools` [`roundrobin` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
>>> from more_itertools import roundrobin
>>> a = [[0,1],[2,3]]
>>> b = [[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> list(roundrobin(a, b))
[[0, 1], [5, 6], [2, 3], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming len(a) == len(b) and you're adding them one by one in turn:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
        c.append(a[i])
        c.append(b[i])
```

However, I would recommend to use `c = deque()`. Since deques are much quicker if you are making a lot of appends.

Comment: Select your code and press CTRL+K in order to format it properly.

Comment: It's more complicated to post code from a smartphone.

Comment: Oh well then, I guess you just indented each line with 4 spaces