# How to return a string formed by alternating characters from two strings?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make this return a string by alternating the letters from the 2 strings inputted. For example, foldStrings("abc","def") should return "adbecf". This is what I have, but all it does is check if the two strings are the same length or not. I'm not really sure where to start.

```
    def foldStrings(string1,string2):
        x=string1
        y=string2
        if len(x)==len(y):
          return "True"
        else:
          return "The two strings are not equal in length."
```

It's the "True" statement that needs to be changed. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Ooh, there's also [How do I interleave strings in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3083829/953482)

Comment: You could start with a good `Python` tutorial...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` and flatten the results:

```
>>> ''.join([''.join(t) for t in zip('abc','def')])
'adbecf'
```

Which works for more than 2 strings as well:

```
>>> ''.join([''.join(t) for t in zip('abc','def','xyz')])
'adxbeycfz'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `zip()` as to iterate two list simultaneously and do `join()` to convert `list` to `str` as::

```
>>> a, b = "abc", "def"
>>> new_list = [i+j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
>>> ''.join(new_list)
'adbecf'
```

My personal favourite (and fastest, check stats at [answer to *alternately appending elements from two lists*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40106860/2063361) is to do it via `list slicing` as:

```
>>> n = list("abc") + list("def")  # create list
>>> n[::2], n[1::2] = a, b  # slice list alternatively
>>> ''.join(n)
'adbecf'
```